# Value of Optional Type 'string?' not unwrapped?

Tags: xcode, swift

I'm not really sure what the error is saying and what I need to do to fix it?
I have tried using both the ! and ?.

Code:

```
var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```

Thanks
<3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that `path` is an optional string (declared as `String?`), so you must unwrap it before providing it to the method. The safest way is using optional binding:

```
if let path = path {
    var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
}
```

however as far as I know, the `dataWithContentsOfFile` method is unavailable - you should use the object initialization counterpart instead:

```
if let path = path {
    var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
}
```

Comment: That's cool, but I'm now having problems with the next line:

    `var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)`

use of unresolved identifier sceneData..

Comment: You probably have to move that line inside the `if` body. However if you are sure that `path` is not nil, you can also use the forced unwrapped operator, as suggested by @moise2022 in his answer

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the `!` to auto unwrap your optional when you are certain that it cannot be null.

```
var sceneData = NSData.dataWithContentsOfFile(path!, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)
```